# R - kableExtra create column with link

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am creating a table with a column with hyperlinks, but those hyperlinks are very long and I wanted to substitute the long text for an image, to click it and to open the link in a new tab.

For example, with this code

```
df = iris[c(1,51,101),]
df$hyperlink = c("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_setosa", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_versicolor", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_virginica")

kable(df,format = "html")%>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("hover", "condensed"), full_width = F)
```

I obtain the last column as a hyperlinks, but what I would like is to put an image that, when clicked, it opens the url (preferably in a new window or tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add clickable images by adding the appropriate html tags. `<a href='...'></a>` is for hyperlinks, and `<img src='...'>` is for images. Simply place the image tag between the opening and closing html tags. Also, be sure to include `escape=FALSE` in the `kable` statement to make it work.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
df = iris[c(1,51,101),]
df$hyperlink = c("<a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_setosa'><img src='setosa.png' /</a>", 
"<a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_versicolor'><img src='versicolor.png' /></a>", 
"<a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_virginica'><img src='virginica.png' /></a>")

kable(df,escape=FALSE,format = "html")%>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("hover", "condensed"), full_width = F)
```